# How to set text in center alignment using itextpdf

Tags: android, text, itext

I want to create a pdf document with a table in it. The text in some cells should be center aligned (horizontally) for some cells.

I have tried a lot, but without any success.

Comment: You claim to have tried a lot. But there is no code in your question. Please show us what you've tried. And more importantly, show us you've done some effort in solving the problem yourself.

Comment: In case you wonder why you received so many down-vote in so little time: No code sample = we don't know which version of iText you are using. No code sample = we don't believe you have tried anything because centering text in cells is easy. *What did you try? Where did you search for information?*

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the examples pages from itextpdf.com

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontProgramFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA_BOLD));

// create paragraph to put in cell
Paragraph para = new Paragraph("Test").setFont(font);
para.setFixedLeading(0);
para.setMultipliedLeading(1);

// create table of 1 row
Table table = new Table(1);

// create cell
Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.setHeight(50);
cell.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
cell.add(para);

// add cell to table
table.addCell(cell);

// add table to document
doc.add(table);

// close document
doc.close();
```

For more information go to http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/clone-alignment-indentation-leading-and-spacing-cells

Comment: There's also a chance that the OP wants to horizontally align text (which is also a no-brainer). In that case, a different method is needed: `cell.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);`